# Postgresql - Syntax error - while using with table_name as

Tags: postgresql

Not sure what needs to be done , i am using pgadmin3 but regardless of the GUI i keep getting the same error .

Below is my query :

```
 with base_table as 
(select row_number() over (partition by p.customer_id order by p.payment_date ) as early_order,
        row_number() over (partition by p.customer_id order by p.payment_date desc) as last_order
    from payment p)
```

> Syntax error at the end of input

I have even tried adding a semicolon at the end, doesnt work :

```
with base_table as 
(select row_number() over (partition by p.customer_id order by p.payment_date ) as early_order,
        row_number() over (partition by p.customer_id order by p.payment_date desc) as last_order
    from payment p);
```

> Syntax error near ";"

The inner query (which is below) works just fine :

```
select row_number() over (partition by p.customer_id order by p.payment_date ) as early_order,
        row_number() over (partition by p.customer_id order by p.payment_date desc) as last_order
    from payment p
```

Its only when i use `with table_name as` , that the errors start to show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add **main select**:

```
with base_table as (
 select row_number() over(partition by p.customer_id order by p.payment_date) as early_order,
        row_number() over(partition by p.customer_id order by p.payment_date desc) as last_order
 from payment p)
SELECT *
FROM base_table
```